# Why am I Running Out of Memory Dimming this Array?

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the situation:

- Excel 2013 (32)
- 4Gb RAM installed
- Excel using ~250Mb RAM with my project workbook open
- **Can't Dim a 20,000 * 700 string array (Error 7, 'Out of Memory')**

I don't understand why this is, I've experimented dimming a smaller array and watching resource usage in Task Manager, observing Excel to use **~28Mb per 10,000** rows (same column count).

If I consider (conservatively) that Excel can only use another 1000Mb, by this logic it should be able to handle 350,000 rows (same column count).

What am I missing? What can I do differently?

Thanks

EDIT: This is the premise the code works on, this simple code recreates the problem.

```
Public arrTest() As String

Sub test()

ReDim arrTest(20000, 700)

End Sub
```

**Edit**

Thanks to user3598756 for a good solution, seems like I had a bit to learn about memory management best practise

Comment: So what does your code actually look like? `Dim arr(0 To 20000) As String`?

Comment: I have the same issue on setting an array 37500*24 for the second time in a loop, I'm just investigating myself, so i'll let you know.  Mines using the variant type to handle setting as range.value

Comment: Thanks, I've added a code example

Comment: what are you using that array for?

Comment: The array contains a bill of materials, lots of rows because there are lots of parts, lots of columns because there are lots of assembly variants. The matrix contains usage quantities.

Comment: So 20000x700 == 14,000,000 ...a lot more than 350,000. ??

Comment: I must not have been clear, 700 columns is assumed in all cases, including 350,000 rows

Comment: what does your last comment mean?

Comment: All arrays are (n * 700)

Comment: is that last edited simple code recreating the issue the _only_ one of the running project? or has your project code more subs/modules other than `Sub test()`?

Comment: Yes, there are several Modules and Subs

Comment: A `Variant` is 12 bytes long, so a declaring a 14,000,000 element array of `Variant` requires ~168MB of memory to build the data area. Older versions of Excel seem to reserve around 500MB for variable storage, although I don't start replicating this on my similarly spec'd machine until I hit around 1.2GB with Excel 2013x32. New versions reserve ~2GB *total process memory* for 32bit installs and ~8GB total for 64 bit. See [this page](http://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsc.htm) for more info.

Comment: @Comintern, but he declared `Public arrTest() As String`, not `Variant`

Comment: @user3598756 - [See his comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246278/why-am-i-running-out-of-memory-dimming-this-array?noredirect=1#comment65829071_39246278).

Comment: @Comintern, IMO "assembly variants" is referring to some _different customization of an assembly_ and have nothing to do with `Variant` types. Which is also confirmed by his code

Comment: @user3598756 - I take "Mines using the variant type to handle setting as range.value" to mean "my array is really of `Variant`, not the code I posted.

Comment: @Comintern, so your comment was addressed to Nathan_Sav, while the lack of any "@" made me think it was to SimonMoss

Comment: @user3598756 Missed that - I'm still not sure how it's relevant to the memory limits of Excel or the size of a 14,000,000 element array of `Variant`.

Comment: @Comintern, it simply didn't comply with OP's code specific data type: that's why I pointed that out. Nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take advantage of one or more of the following techniques:

1. **allocate memory *when* needed**

   do really you need `arrTest()` array to be `Public`?

   `Public` arrays variables are allocated as soon as they are "sized" and stay there until it ends

   this means that every subsequent memory allocations brought along by other subs variables declarations get added to the `Public` ones

   should you need `arrTest()` in `Sub test()` only then move its declaration into this latter

   ```
   Sub test()

       Dim arrTest(20000, 700)

   End Sub
   ```

   and as soon as you exit it, the `arrTest()` memory allocation gets released

   otherwise, and for the same reasons, should you need `arrTest()` across multiple subs than:
2. declare it in the very first `Sub` that uses it
3. pass it as a parameter to other `Subs` that need to use/process it

   ```
        Sub main()

            sub1 '<--| call 'Sub1(): at this stage no memory allocation has taken place for any 'arrTest()' array
            'once out of 'sub1' any memory allocation for any 'arrTest()' array has been released
        End Sub

        Sub sub1()
            Dim arrTest(20000, 700) As String '<--| here memory allocation takes place for 'arrTest()' array

            sub2 arrTest '<--| pass 'arrTest()' array to Sub2

            'at exiting this sub, the 'arrTest()' memory allocation gets released
        End Sub

        Sub sub2(stringArray() As String)
            'here 'arrTest()' array memory allocation stays the same

            'code to exploit passed array
        End Sub
   ```
4. **allocate *as much* memory *as* needed**

   standing what per previous point 1, size your array for what *actually* needed, which is also the reason why you would use *dynamic* arrays instead of *static* ones

   ```
   Sub sub1()
       Dim arrTest() As String
       Dim nRows As Long, ncols As Long

       With Worksheets("Data")
           nRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
           ncols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       End With

       ReDim arrTest(1 To nRows, 1 To ncols) As String '<--| here memory allocation takes place for 'arrTest()' array

       sub2 arrTest '<--| pass 'arrTest()' array to Sub2

       'at exiting this sub, the 'arrTest()' memory allocation gets released
   End Sub
   ```
5. **work with worksheet range**

   should all previous efforts be in vane, then you just use Excel ranges and as much its  built-in function as you can to exploit data already stored there

   this will most probably raise performance issues, but at least it runs...

hope all this can help you out

Comment: @SimonMoss, did you get through it?

Comment: Would the _brave_ downvoter show up and give any explanation so as to both have people know why they shouldn't follow thi answer and teach me how to improve it?